# how to write a (php) web app to send to the client a .txt file with values client has inserted into a JS prompt box

Tags: javascript, php

I wish to develop a (toy) app to 1) to let a user to fill in a JS prompt box with a couple of values, write them within a .txt file, and 2) sent the latter back to the user.

I am able to do either one, but not to combine them in a single app.

I have these two short scripts:

main.html

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
        function myFunction() {
 var person = prompt("Please enter your name", "Harry Potter");
 var mail = prompt("Please enter your email", "Harry Potter");
 document.getElementById("person").value = person;
 document.getElementById("mail").value = mail;
 document.getElementById("form").submit();   <<<< NOTE
 }
```

NOTE it seems that the submit is such that somehow it makes fail the  readfile(); below

```
 </script>
 </head>
 <body>

 <form id="form" action="minor.php?file=abc.txt" method="post">
 <input type="hidden" name="person" id="person" />
 <input type="hidden" name="mail" id="mail" />
 </form>

 <a onclick=myFunction(); href="minor.php?file=abc.txt">see abc.txt</a>';
 </body> 
 </html>
```

NOTE I tried both `action="minor.php?file=abc.txt"` and  `href="minor.php?file=abc.txt"` above (not both at the same time!), and either way something is missing (see different outputs I get below)

minor.php

```
<?php  

 $file_directory = "Files";  
 $file = $_GET['file'];  
 $file_array = explode('/', $file);  
 file_array_count = count($file_array);  
 $filename = $file_array[$file_array_count-1];  
 $file_path = dirname(__FILE__).'/'.$file_directory.'/'.$file; 

 if (is_writable($file_path)) {
 if (!$handle = fopen($file_path, 'a')) {
     echo "Cannot open file ($file_path)";
     exit;
       }

 foreach($_POST as $key => $req){  // or use $_REQUEST
    if (fwrite($handle, $key."--".$req."\n")== FALSE){  
    echo "Cannot write to file ($file_path)";
    exit;
   }
   }
 fclose($handle);

 } else {
  echo "The file $file_path is not writable";
  }

 if(file_exists($file_path)) {
header('Content-type: text/plain'); 
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename={$filename}");
readfile($file_path); //Read and stream the file
}
else {
echo "Sorry, the file does not exist!";
}                              
?>
```

This is the different outputs I get, when I shuffle a couple of data:

```
case A
document.getElementById("form").submit(); included
action="" (empty)
href="minor.php?file=abc.txt"
----
DO download abc.txt
Nothing written into abc.txt
access.log: "GET .../minor.php?file=abc.txt HTTP/1.1" 200 13

case B
//document.getElementById("form").submit();  // Commented out
action="" (empty)
href="minor.php?file=abc.txt"
-----
DO download abc.txt
Nothing written into abc.txt (clear why)
access.log:  "GET .../minor.php?file=abc.txt HTTP/1.1" 200

case C
document.getElementById("form").submit();  included
action="minor.php?file=abc.txt"
href="" (empty)
-----
DOES NOT download abc.txt
access.log "GET .../main.html HTTP/1.1" 304 (error??)
```

Your help is welcome.

Comment: Can you add the error(s) you encounter when executing this ?

Comment: there is not an error. If I keep `document.getElementById("form").submit()`, I do not get the file back; if I don't, clearly I do not get the form value on the server side ($_POST is empty). Should I check some log somewhere?

Comment: "somehow it makes fail the readfile();", "and either way something is missing"... I might miss something here but some clarification might be welcome. Regarding your issue, why use JS prompts when a plain form would be sufficient IMHO ? As for your minor.php, what result do you get ? An error ? A redirection ?

Comment: @NaeiKinDus see edit. I hope it is clear how I get the different outputs.

Comment: You have no element with the id `form`, so `document.getElementById("form").submit();` can only cause an error. And you are using a link to call your function, but you neglected to prevent the default action of the link - so the browser makes a GET request for the link target, and never actually submits your form.

Comment: @CBroe. Sorry for the typo. How do I prevent the default action of the link?

Comment: @CBroe Something like  `<a onclick="myFunction();return false;" href="">see abc.txt</a>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the following code does what I was looking for:

(minor.php as above, but use `foreach($_GET ... )` instead of `foreach($_POST ... )` )

**main.html**

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction() {
var person = prompt("Please enter your name", "Harry Potter");
var mail = prompt("Please enter your email", "Harry Potter");
    document.getElementById("clickhere").innerHTML="";
    document.getElementById("mainlink").innerHTML="please download now"; 
    document.getElementById("mainlink").href="minor.php?file=abc.txt&"+"person="+person+"&mail="+mail+""; 
    document.getElementById('mainlink').click();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div onclick=myFunction(); id="clickhere">click here</div>
<a  href="#" id="mainlink"></a>
</body>
</html>
```

I welcome other answers with improved/alternative code.